# Using a template class as a template argument

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

Consider the following code:

```
template <class MyB>
struct A {
    MyB *b_;
};

template <template <class> class MyA>
struct B {
    MyA<B> *a_; // How come B can be used as a complete type here?
};
```

The comment states my question: `B` is a template, so how come it can be used as a complete type in `MyA<B>`?

Comment: You're merely taking a pointer to MyA<B>, thus MyA<B> doesn't have to be a complete type, thus B neither.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the scope of a `template` declaration, the template's name alone designates a complete type, for every automatically generated specialization, synonymous to that specialization. Consider, e.g.,

```
template<class A> struct B {
    B();
    B &operator=(B const &);
    typedef B This;
};
```

Comment: In your example, is `B` just a short-hand notation for `B<A>`?

Comment: Yes, you can think of it that way.

Comment: BTW, is the name `This` idiomatic?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm using it for this purpose, but have never met anywhere else. It's been inspired by that, in Scala, every value belongs to its singleton subtype called `type`.

Comment: I use `MyType` for this purpose, but am not sure whether others will easily understand what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

`B` *will* be a complete type by the time someone gets round to using a particular template instance of `B`.

Remember that template code is not "compiled" until an instance is created.

Answer (score 2):

Within an instantiation of a class template `X`, the name `X` can be used to refer either to the template or to the current instantiation of the template.

From [**[temp.local]**](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.local#1):

> 1 - Like normal (non-template) classes, class templates have an *injected-class-name* (Clause 9). The *injected-class-name*
>   can be used as a *template-name* or a *type-name*.

Comment: What is temp.local?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning it is the reference of a section of the Standard, currently numbered 14.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

> How come B can be used as a complete type here?

`B` does not have to be a complete time for you to declare a pointer of type `MyA<B>`.

You can use:

```
template <typename T> struct Foo { T* ptr;};
struct Bar;
Foo<Bar>* ptr = nullptr;
```

You can even use:

```
template <typename T> struct Foo { T* ptr;};
struct Bar;
Foo<Bar> obj;
```

since `Foo` does not depend on the definition of `Bar` in its own definition.